# What is the smallest squarefree number $n$ with $gnu(n)=79$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

I am searching the smallest squarefree number $n$ with $gnu(n)=79$. $n$ must have more then $3$ prime factors because $p+2\ne 79$ and $p+4\ne 79$ for every prime $p$.

The maximum possible number of $gnu(pqrs)$, where $p<q<r<s$ are primes, is $p^2+pq+3p+2q+8\ne 79$ for all primes $p,q$ with $p<q$.

But there might be a squarefree number $n$ with $4$ prime factors and $gnu(n)=79$.

> What is the smallest squarefree number $n$ with $gnu(n)=79$ ?

Comment: The smallest example $n$ is greater than $3\times 10^8$.

Comment: Can you define $\text{gnu}(x)$?

Comment: $gnu(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$

Comment: Conway indicates [here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf) that R. Keith Dennis has computed it. But I could not find this paper.

Comment: $gnu(19,214,615,649)=79$